# Updating the content of a database with the content of another database

Tags: sql, sqlite

im new to SQL and can't figure out why my sql script isn't working.
I've two databases, and my task is to update a column of a specific table with the content of the same table in the other database if the conditions are met. The tables and columns of both databases have the same names, just party different content. I already looked through a lot of similar questions, but couldn't make it work / figure out what i did wrong.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COLUMN_1 = Database2.TABLE1.COLUMN_1 
WHERE Database2.TABLE1.COLUMN_2 LIKE '%DIN276%';
```

(Im running the query on the first database)

Comment: You need to come up with a correlated scalar subquery that returns a single value to set the column to. `UPDATE table1 SET col1 = (SELECT t2.col1 FROM db2.table2 AS t2 WHERE ....)`

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL database does not support cross-database queries.

You must create in your Database1 a foreighn data wrapper for TABLE1 from Database2, then you can perform queries with your TABLE1 in Database1 together with data from TABLE1 of Database2.

Comment: Missed this, but same applies to SQLite too, except sqlite has no fdw. So, it's impossible to make cross-database queries with SQLite, IMHO.

Comment: You can attach multiple sqlite database files to one connection. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html